# AmpScript redirect not working in if/else

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, redirect, if

Hello I'm working on a Cloud Page in Marketing Cloud. I'm trying to set a redirect based on the result of an object update in a connected CRM.

Example code below.

```
%%[
    var @campaginMemberId, @city, @update
        
    set @campaginMemberId = RequestParameter("CampaignMemberID") 
    set @city = RequestParameter("city-input") 

    if empty(@update) then
        set @update = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject( 
        "CampaignMember", @campaginMemberId,
        "City__c", @city
        )
    endif

    if @update == 1 then 
        redirect("http://example.com/thank-you") 
    elseif (empty(@update)) or (@update == 0) then
        redirect(concat("http://example.com/error?CampaignMemberID=", @campaginMemberId))
    endif
]%%
```

The problem is that when I try to set the ending if/else to check the update result, it only works if I set the conditions like this

```
if @update == 1 then 
    redirect("http://example.com/thank-you") 
elseif (empty(@update)) then
    redirect(concat("http://example.com/error?CampaignMemberID=", @campaginMemberId))
endif
```

When I set it like this it works like a charm and I don't get any errors.
If instead I only set an else instead of an elseif it stops working, and it doesen't even work if I set the second condition as `@update == 0`. I always get this error message

> **Redirect Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in in content with an HTTP context.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you getting the error message exactly?

Comment: As @AdamSpriggs said, this looks likely that other code is causing the issue. If I hard code `@update`, `@campaignMemberId` and `@city` using your above sample, it works perfectly.

Comment: It is literally the only code in the page, I'm using it as a redirect middle page to update the record. I'm getting the error by wrapping the code in a SSJS try/catch

Answer (score 1):

I'll postulate that you have some other code that's interfering.

I don't have any issues with this simple test in a CloudPage.

Works (redirects with GUID parameter value):

```ampscript
%%[
    var @update

    if @update == 1 then 
       redirect("http://sprignaturemoves.com/?whee=update")
    else
       redirect(concat("http://sprignaturemoves.com/?whee=", GUID()))
    endif
    
]%%
```

Also works (redirects with update parameter value):

```ampscript
%%[
    var @update
    set @update = 1

    if @update == 1 then 
       redirect("http://sprignaturemoves.com/?whee=update")
    else
       redirect(concat("http://sprignaturemoves.com/?whee=", GUID()))
    endif
    
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully explain the behavior, but maybe try and streamline it so that you only change the url inside the condition and just place one "unconditional" redirect at the end.

In this example, I've moved it to inline, you could also try to keep it inside the `%%[]%%` brackets, right after `endif`.

```
%%[ 
if @update == 1 then 
    set @url = "http://example.com/thank-you"
else
    set @url = concat("http://example.com/error?CampaignMemberID=", @campaginMemberId)
endif
]%%%%=redirect(@url)=%%
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error both if I put it inside or outside the brackets